# Laravel Migration pivote table give error of make

Tags: php, laravel-5

> php artisan make:migration:pivote products category

[image: Error is here]

There are no commands defined in the "make:migration" namespace.
Did you mean this?
make

please solve this error ? thanks in advance 
**laravel version 5.4**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo **pivote** instead of **pivot**

```
php artisan make:migration:pivot products category
```